Grub2 on dual boot, boots windonws repair
I made a clean install of windows 10 in a acer nitro in a ssd new drive. Then, i installed Zorin OS. The dual boot is not working correctly. It shows Zorin, then 2 option of win system, one in the HDD and another in SSD. The one in HD I guess its a backup. Doest matter which one I choose (on SSD or on HD) the result is the same, its starts a repair boot loader from windows and its totally unable to boot.
I tryied to update grub (suno update-grub). I received the following lines on the terminal:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/zorin/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-35-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

I am suspecting that the problem is the file grub2 is selecting to call windows boot.  Anyone knows how to solve that in order to ask me which OS i want everytime I turn on the computer?
Just one thing, if i press F2 and enter in the bios, and select "Windows boot manager" located in SSD it works well.

Grub only boots working Windows. That means fast startup/hibernation must be off, bitlocker must be off and chkdsk not required. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? You show Windows UEFI boot loaders in two different ESP's - efi system partitions. So may have two UEFI boot entries both saying Windows?

I think @oldfred is correct. Haven't dual-booted with BitLocker myself, but this answer from 2 years earlier says you need Secure Boot enabled and Windows booted from boot menu -not grub-. https://superuser.com/a/1707256/1728891 P.S. using fast-boot should work with grub AFAIR, but then files are inaccessible from Linux to not corrupt data of course.

Yes, I can boot windows through UEFI boot menu in the bios, and yes i see 3 option on the bios, one without name and 2 with Windows Boot Manager one pointed to the ssd and the other pointed to the HD. The HD I never tryied, the ssd works. the unnamed is grub, when acess grub menu.

Thank you both. the Secure boot is enable.

I really need to dual boot (since I need package office to work and wine is not working with the latest version- and i need it offline- my connection is pretty bad), so i am trying to find whats wrong. i did several tests but nothing worked. I am thing about using other distribution instead of zorin (i just picked up zorin because I thought it would be easy to maybe make wine work- which was not the case). Anyway, I keep searching and testing to find where the error is.

I really need to dual boot... N, you don't. You can run one of the OSes as a virtual machine. And you don't need Microsoft Office either but if you think you do, you can easily install it on Windows in a virtual machine. Or run whatever you want in the Linux VM installed in Windows. Dual boot is better, of course because both OSes will be running with the full hardware capabilities but if it's too much trouble then a VM is preferable. I think you should rethink your priorities.

I actually need MS Office because I work to a company that works with advanced things from MS Office (I use LibreOffice for my personal stuff) that dont work correctly online ( I did several tests about it) besides, there are a couple programms developed by the IT team from this company that only runs in windows (I tried on linux, with and without wine). I tought carefully about all my options ( wine, VMs and dual boot) wine i cannot run the most recently version, which is a problem (as i said above)- tried out wine, wine with bottles, playforlinux nothing worked.

VM i am giving another try (my problem: vmware is not downloading doesnt matter wnat i do- terminal ou site). I used to have dual boot like 15 years ago and no problems. The systems were Ubuntu and win XP. But by that time, i did several configurations manually. I dont recall how i did that, so, soon, i am give another try with zorin make more things manually and if it doesnt work, I'll try with Ubuntu. or Linux Mint or Manjaro (but  dont think it works well along with windows). The reason why i choosed Zorin is because Windows and because Nvidia.

How I have solved the dual boot problem.
I used to have a Hdd and a SSD, i wanted to change OS to the SSD and dual boot with windows and Linux. Mistake one: tried with tools (free) to move the OS and all HDD content to SSD. It did not work (or better it did this partially because the HDD was bigger than the SSD), it left on the HDD the OS, some partitions and some old files. eventhough i think i formated it.
So, first of all what a person should do is back up all files to a external HDDor penDrive. Than, remove the HDD from the computer and clean install first the windows on SSD from a pendrive. Then put back the HDD erase everything there (writting 0 or 1), - i used the minitool partition (which is free for that operation and to the following), then with the same programe erase all the partitions on HDD. Result: you will have some free space (all the free space from HDD, actually), in a HDD not formated at all. Then i atributed some space to files (NTFS type).
Then i installed Debian 12 from a usb pendrive. I made all manually (the partitions). And voilá dual boot works pretty well.
